# Como extrair uma informaçao de uma request python

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict


  url = f"http://localhost/teste.php"
            headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
            headers["Accept"] = "*/*"
            resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Então eu tenho esse simples script, eu gostaria de poder pegar uma informaçao que esta no response dele

Exemplo: Nome":"Joao"

e eu gostaria de poder extrair apenas o nome Joao
Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você poderia fornecer um exemplo de *response* que pode ser recebida?

Comment: {"Registro":{"nome":"joao","email":"joao@gmail.com"}}
gostaria apenas pegar o nome joao

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta, veja se isso resolve o seu problema.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode usar a biblioteca `json`:

```py
import json
import requests

url = "http://localhost/teste.php"
headers = requests.structures.CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Accept"] = "*/*"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Transforma o texto da resposta em um dicionário
data = json.loads(response.text)

nome = data["Registro"]["nome"]
print(nome)
# Imprime joao
```